# Making a module use functions and variables defined within the main program

Tags: python, module, irc

I'm making an IRC bot for my network. To make the code cleaner, I am defining functions in modules. All these modules are in a folder called "plugins". One module *say* calls the function *sendMsg* and fails because it's trying to run a function defined in the main program. I also want to have this module to be able to access variables defined in the main program after the program has started.

```
import socket
import time
import re

from plugins.say import *

host = "irc.somenetwork.net"
port = 6667
nick = "ircbot"
channels = "##bottesting"
s = socket.socket()

def connect():
   s.connect((host, port))
   s.send("NICK %s\r\n" % nick)
   s.send("USER %s %s nul :%s\r\n" % (nick, nick, nick))
   time.sleep(3)
   s.send("JOIN %s\r\n" % channels)
   time.sleep(3)

def sendMsg(chan, msgSend):
   s.send("PRIVMSG %s :%s\r\n" % (chan,msgSend))
#   print "Sending message \"%s\" to channel/user \"%s\"" % (msgSend, chan)

def quitServ(quitMsg="m8bot"):
   s.send("QUIT %s\r\n" % quitMsg)

connect()

while 1:
   msgRaw = s.recv(1024)
   print msgRaw
   if msgRaw == "":
      break
   if "PING" in msgRaw:
      print "Pong!"
      PONG = msgRaw.split(' ')
      PONG[0] = PONG[0].replace('PING','PONG')
      PONG = ' '.join(PONG)
      s.send("%s\r\n" % PONG)
   if "PRIVMSG" in msgRaw:
#      print "PRIVMSG detected"
      user = ''.join(re.compile("(?<=:).{0,}(?=.{0,}!)").findall(msgRaw.split(' ')[0]))
      channel = msgRaw.split(' ')[2]
      command = (' '.join(msgRaw.split(' ')[3:]).replace(":","",1)).split(' ')[0]
      msg = ''.join((' '.join(msgRaw.split(' ')[3:]).replace(":","",1)).split(' ')[1:]).replace("\r\n","")

      if not "#" in channel:
         channel = user
      print "Nick: %s\nChannel: %s\nCommand: %s\nMsg: %s" % (user,channel,command,msg)
      if ".quit" in command:
         if msg:
            quitServ(str(msg))
         else:
            quitServ()
      if ".hello" in command:
#         print "Attempting to send Hello World message."
         sendMsg(channel, "Hello World!")
      if ".say" in command:
         say(msg)

quitServ()
```

This is my program. function *say()* is as follows:

```
def say(msg):
   sendMsg(channel, "You said: %s" % msg)
```

I can see what the problem is, but I don't know how I would fix this. Feedback appreciated :)

-Nia

Answer (score 0):

Try `import __main__` in your say.py.
And then your say function should look something like this:

```
def say():
   __main__.sendMsg(channel, "You said: %s" % msg)
```

But this is not a best solution. Just solution with less code changes.